# read excel cell containing formulas with link to external workbook with numpy/panda

Tags: python, numpy, reference, external

I need to read an excel file with a cell containing a reference to an external excel workbook in the same path as the origin excel file. Is there any function/parameter to get the reference in such cell with numpy/panda?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'C:\\your_path\\Book1.xlsx')
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
name = sheet_names[0]
sheet_ranges = wb[name]
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)
df
```

Result:

```
        0       1       2       3       4
0  field1  field2  field3  field4  field5
1       1  =A2*10  =B2*10  =C2*10  =D2*10
2       1  =A3*10  =B3*10  =C3*10  =D3*10
3       1  =A4*10  =B4*10  =C4*10  =D4*10
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer ASH.
The result that I am looking for is the following: If I have a cell in "Book1.xlsm" with a formula including a reference to another different workbook (example 'externalwb.xlsm') with the following cell content:

=[externalwb.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$2

I need to obtain the real referred file name.
However this is what I am getting now with openpyxl:

=[1]Sheet1'!$F$2

Is there any way to get the real cell content " =[externalwb.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$2 " with numpy/panda instead of "=[1]Sheet1'!$F$2"?
Thanks again!!

Comment: I get the same result: [1].  I guess it's not designed to show fully qualified references to other files.  VBA will do that for you!  You can go with a VBA solution if you really need to do this kind of thing.

Comment: I don't know if you are still struggling with this, but I just opened an issue in the openpyxl repo: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/2093